# Test Suite for Arithmetic Expression Parser

Tags: parsing, testing, evaluation, arithmetic-expressions, test-suite

I am writing a simple parser (in JavaScript, and, later, in Swift) to evaluate basic arithmetic expressions such as `1+2*3` and `3*(4+5)`.

I have a working version, but I would like to test whether it is reliable.

Is there a test suite of arithmetic expressions to run through my parser?

By way of context, I am writing my own parser rather than looking for a library or using built-in functionality such as `eval`. This is for the following reasons:

- Experience
- It allows me to parse expressions not normally acceptable in parsers such as `3(4+5)`, `2×3`, `√16` and `6²`, as well as the use of special variables
- Experience

Comment: I suppose if you intend to accept "expressions not normally acceptable in parsers", then you are unlikely to find an appropriate​ standard test suite :-)